# Drawing links among words in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I would like to know if something like this (see the picture above) is possible in HTML/CSS/Javascript and if so, what are the frameworks/technology that I should look at.

I have a text in a HTML page and I would like to highlight some words in it using different colours according to different meanings (let's say 3 types, 'name of software': blue, 'numbers': grey, 'name of people: 'red'). Then, an this is the tricky part for me, I would like to draw directed arrows among these highlighted words in a way that resizing the window will automatically keep anchored the arrows regardless to the changed position of the words.

Right now I am solving the highlighting part using a particular tag for the words to be highlighted and an ad-hoc CSS decorator with the property background colour accordingly set. The linking part is literally a mystery for me.

I thank you all for your help,
michele.

PS. I would prefer doing that on the client side.

Comment: Yep, canvas. Keep your types separated by class, enumerate through the locations with said class name, and draw the arrows.

Comment: if you don't like canvas use regular png with transparent background PS will help you on that have fun.

Comment: I recommend dividing this into two posts – one for how to highlight the text, the other for how to draw the linking arrows.  You'll get plenty of good answers for part one, but only a handful of people could help with part two.

Comment: Thanks guys. Thanks a lot. It seems to me that there is no solution which will preserve the text in the page. I need to create a picture, isnt'it? Even by using the HTML5 Canvas the user will lose the possibility of, let's say, highlight the text in the browser, copy parts of it and so on. There will be no text in the end, just a picture. Is it correct?

Thanks,

Comment: fascinating idea! if you don't want to go the canvas route, and are willing to use JQuery, check out [`$(el).position()`](http://devdocs.io/jquery/position)

Comment: The canvas would hold the linking lines only.  Your text would still be HTML, so you could interact with it as usual.

Comment: What happen with canvas if I resize the window (when the text is rearranged)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do loads of JavaScript code for this but I will simply tell you the steps. To achive your goal you need to:

- parse every word in your paragraph by using `split()` method.

  `var words = yourparagraph.split(" ");`
- create an array that contains called `name_of_software` and push the software names in this array.
- do the very above thing for people names and call the array `people_names`.

  `var name_of_software = ["html", "css", "javascript"];`

  `var people_names = ["michele", "george", "john"];`
- create corresponding css for the highlightings.

  `span.red { background: red; overflow: hidden; display: block; }`

  `span.grey { background: grey; overflow: hidden; display: block; }`

  `span.blue { background: blue; overflow: hidden; display: block; }`
- Do a loop like this:

.

```
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    if($.inArray(words[i].toLowerCase(), name_of_software)) {
        // The word is a name of a software. Give blue class.
    } else if($.inArray(words[i].toLowerCase(), people_names)) {
        // The word is a name of a person. Give red class.
    } else if(isNaN(words[i])) {
        // The word is a number. Give grey class.
    }
}
```

I didn't test it or create a working version of it. Hope this steps will guide you to achive your goal.

Comment: It seems to me you are suggesting a valid methodology to solve the highlighting part only. Am I right? What about the linking part?

Thanks, michele.